# Complex analysis Analytic function solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have proved the following the if f(z) is analytic and satisfies the condition $|f|^2 =1 $everywhere in the domain D. Prove that f is const in D and determine all the possible values of the const.

Proof. $|f|^2 = |u+iv|^2 =u^2 +v^2 =k^2 $

$uu_x +vv_x =0,$

$uu_y +vv_y =0$

subbing $v_x = -u_y$ in the first equation and v_y =u_x in the second, we have the following.

$uu_x -vu_y=0$

$uu_y -vu_x=0$

solving we get

$u^2 +v^2)u_x =0,

$u^2 +v^2)u_y=0.

=> $1=u^2 +v^2 \neq 0$, then $u_x=u_y=0$. And by the Cauchy Riemann equations we have $u_x=v_y=0.$ Which means that both u and v are constant; hence f is constant. I was just wondering is the second part that all the solutions are of the form $\sqrt{u^2 +v^2}=1$

Comment: Also, as copper.hat said, if $f(z)$ is analytic and non-constant then  $f(z) = f(z_0)+ C (z-z_0)^n + o(|z-z_0|^n)$ with $C \ne 0, n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ so that $f(z)$ maps a neighborhood of $z_0$ to a neighborhood of $f(z_0)$ and $|f(z)|$ isn't constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an intuition perspective, I find the (complex analysis) open mapping theorem to be very useful.

In this case, if $f$ is non constant, $f(D)$ would be open, hence we could not have $|f(x)| = 1$ on $D$. hence $f$ is constant, so the problem reduces to
finding constants $c$ that satisfy $|c|=1$.

Hence $f(z) = e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta$.